# Is model theory needed to understand ordinal logic?

Tags: logic, model-theory, ordinals, advice

By ordinal logic, I mean turing's ordinal logic.

I'm going to learn first order logic, elementary set theory, basic computability, and godelian incompleteness as prerequisites for ordinal logic. But, since I'm a math beginner, I don't know if I will need model theory to understand it.

Comment: For what it's worth, I recommend the book "Inexhaustibility" over Turing's original paper, which is quite dense and uses non-modern notation.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I was planning to read "Inexhaustibility" before turing's original paper. Does "Inexhaustibility" teach ordinal logic well? Perhaps, I wouldn't have to torture myself with turing's papers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps not a lot of model theory, but some. The basic results known to Turing when he did that work probably come into play, and in any case will serve you well as general culture: the completeness theorem and the compactness theorem, and possibly the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem.

The [**completeness theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del's_completeness_theorem) in its most basic form says that a sentence of first order logic is provable *iff* it is true in all models. Provability is, of course, relative to some particular deductive system: Hilbert-style systems consisting of axioms and rules of deduction, Gentzen's sequent calculus, the later "natural deduction" systems — these are all equivalent.

A more general form of the completeness theorem states: a theory $T$ (a set of first-order sentences) is consistent *iff* it has a model. Consistency of $T$ means that no contradictions can be proved using the sentences of $T$ as axioms.

The [**compactness theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem) says that a set of first order sentences S is consistent iff every finite subset of S is consistent.

For languages with countably many non-logical symbols, the (downward) [**Lowenheim-Skolem theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem#Downward_part) states that if a theory $T$ in such a language has a model, then it has a countable model. There is also an *upward* Lowenheim-Skolem theorem, which says that if a theory has an infinite model, then it has models of all infinite cardinalities greater than that of the model. The theorem reveals a limitation of first-order logic: a first-order theory cannot characterize its models uniquely, up to isomorphism.

Comment: Do you think Maria Manzano, Model Theory, Oxford Logic Guides 37 (OUP, 1999) covers everything you mentioned?

Comment: There's an excellent chance it does, as I think any book with such a title has to; but let me see if I can 'look inside' at all... Yes, as per the table of contents, it does: https://global.oup.com/academic/product/model-theory-9780198538516?cc=us&lang=en&# Chapter headings for each of the theorems I mentioned :)